# Impersonation for Web application type client

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs

I have a web application type client with a daemon thread that uses the admin accounts oauth token to fetch the documents of other users and performs various operations on document delete,share etc., What I see is that the domain administrator has only read privileges on the documents in other users drive so the call

```
drive.files().delete(id).execute()
```

wont work. Is ther a way to impersonate or tranfer permissions to admin account while using admin accounts token itself. Please note that I cannot make any call with users token at this point.

Answer (score 0):

To impersonate other users, you must use a service account. See:

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation